# Good material to read on Map in F#

Tags: f#

Please help with the following exercise:
[image]

what are good source of material can I read to understand how to use Map in F#?

I tried to understand how to use Map.

I tried:

```
let holidays =
    Map.empty.
        Add("Christmas", "Dec. 25");;
```

It works then I tried:

```
let holidays =
    Map.empty.
        Add("Christmas", "Dec. 25")
        Add("Halloween", "Oct. 31");;
```

and it gave an error

I had to put a dot after the first Add statement like this:

```
let holidays =
    Map.empty.
        Add("Christmas", "Dec. 25").
        Add("Halloween", "Oct. 31");;
```

I'm wondering why is that.

So then that means

```
let holidays =
    Map.empty;;
```

is how we create a new map.  But I want a map of type Map (Team, Points).
So I tried:

```
let exmaple =
    Map.empty.
        Add ("Superman", Points 8);;
val exmaple : Map<string,Points> = map [("Superman", Points 8)]
```

But this is of type map(string, Points) not map(Team, Points).

Also, How do I write "<" after map on stackoverflow so that things follow "<" do appear(that is why i use map() instead of map<>)?

Please help.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map-module-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Comment: Please help, you know when you start an assignment and you have no idea what is going on? How do I create a variable of type Map<Team,Points>? I tried :Map<Team "Vegeta", Point 5>;;, [("Vegeta", 10)];;,   Map<Team, Points> [("Vegeta", 10)];; because I though Map<Team, Points> is a constructor.

Comment: BTW, very good material to learn about F#: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com

Comment: thanks! Also, do you know how to iterate through elements in a map like a::af for list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways of creating an empty `Map<Team,Points>` are:

```
let holidays : Map<Team, Points> = Map.empty
let holidays'                    = Map.empty : Map<Team, Points>  // this also works
let holidays''                   = Map.empty // even this works if followed by usage
```

You can add elements with either `.Add(t, p)` or with `Map.add t p`:

```
let twoAdded  = holidays       .Add("Superman", Points 6)       .Add("Batman", Points 5)
let twoAdded' = holidays |> Map.add "Superman" (Points 6) |> Map.add "Batman" (Points 5)
```

The second way is the functional way.

Your type `Team` and `string` are the same because:

```
type Team = string
```

is just an alias not a new type.